# Tensorflow first epoch is extremely slow (maybe related to pool_allocator)

Tags: tensorflow, tcmalloc

I am training a model built with TF. At the first epoch, TF is slower than the next epochs by a factor of *100 and I am seeing messages like:

`I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 958 to 1053`

As suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/ja7FlGrvh-E), I tried to use tcmalloc by setting `LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so"`, but it didn't help.

Any idea on how to make the first epoch run faster?

Comment: Do you set any options so that TF does not gulp all GPU memory?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is a hardware issue. For the first epoch TF (the same as other DL libraries, like PyTorch as discussed [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/drastically-slow-speed-at-first-epoch/12551)) caching information about data as discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13114) by @ppwwyyxx

> If each data has different size, TF can spend a large amount of time running cudnn benchmarks for each data and store them in cache